# Difference between magento 2.1 and 2.2

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-core, magento2.2

I'm currently working on Magento 2.2. And found that In Magento 2.2 core team made many changes in files and folder structure, deleted many files, replaced classes and many other things.

One other important change found, that in **Magento 2.2 generation folder location changed**

**Change location from**

> magento2.1/var/generation

**To**

> magento2.2/generated

Added new folder **metadata** in generated folder what is use of it?

Other things found that **add new i18n folder** at **`magento22/app`** like Magento 1 **`app/locale`**

Does anyone has found more changes or differences in Magento 2.2?

Comment: You  can read features of Magento2.2 on http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/release-notes-2-2-prerelease1-CE.html

Comment: @KeyurShah Thanks for the link. But I need technical difference like anyone faces problem during converting modules from Magento 2.1 to 2.2.

Comment: Hey Prince could you please tell me what is the best way to create dependencies in magento 2 & how and When to use which classes in magento for block creation & rendering the required things in our desired phtml file & in our own way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare both version from below link

https://github.com/magento/magento2/compare/2.1...2.2

Open File Changed tab

you can find here all changes related to file structure as well as code changes in files.

Comment: OMG! "Showing 26,804 changed files with 608,084 additions and 222,469 deletions." :O