# How to update Magento 2.1.7 to Magento 2.2 ? Is it possible to upgrade?

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I wanted to know is it possible to update **Magento from 2.1.7 to 2.2** ?
Or what is a solution to update all Magento  2.1.7 stores to Magento 2.2 ? 
If we will update it then what are the challenges for that we have to be prepared?

Please let me know is there any solution for this or not.

Comment: I dont think upgrade is available for 2.2 now though it can be possible in future.  You can view this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/192522/29175 for details on this.

Comment: Currently, it's not available for 2.2. I have just received an email from Magento that: `We expect the final release will be published in the next few weeks` from now(Wed Sep 13, 2017).

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh Yes But as we should be prepared earlier. 
as magento  team have already mentioned that they have completed development form magneot2.2 now they will test and improve it. 
so we should be prepared for it. so i am curious to know about it.

Comment: @Jai Yes I already checked that thanks. But I am finding way if its possible to upgrade or not. so based on that we can plan our projects.

Comment: It will be easy upgrade like we are upgrading now from 2.1.2 - 2.1.8 etc. So I think you can wait for that. More concern should be new features and architecture.

Comment: Yes, you can and it's available from this morning.

Comment: @St3phan Means migration available?

Comment: Magento 2.2.0+ makes changes to how it serializes json data for the system config. So you might encounter issues there.

Comment: Did anyone upgraded to 2.2.x and it working fine? I didnt try but want to use latest 2.2.x if there is no issues in it. I hope magento team will stick to it now, not expecting 2.3 or 2.4 ...lol

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Below is how I upgraded from 2.1.9 to 2.2.0 :

```
bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.0 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf var/generation/*
chmod +x bin/magento
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

For further upgrades, change the version number:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.4 --no-update
```

Comment: magento 2.x no longer has `var/generation/` directory. Use `rm -rf var/generation` instead

Comment: Do we need to upgrade versions one by one or is it normal to upgrade to the recent one directly. For example from 2.2.2 to 2.2.5. Should I upgrade gradually to 2.2.3 then 2.2.4 and finally to 2.2.5? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are custom modules working fine after up-gradation?

Comment: Do mind to check the minimum PHP version supported by Magento 2.2.X !!

Answer (score 5):

I had problems with some custom modules.
Check for updates from Magento 2.2 for custom modules used on:

> Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterface - add new method getMessage

(Modules Smtp, Mail etc)

> Magento\Rule\Model\AbstractModel - serialization replaced by json

(Modules used Rule)

Answer (score 0):

**Upgrade Magento 2.1.7 to Magento 2.2.2**

Edit composer.json

```
"version": "2.1.7" replace with "version": "2.2.2"
"magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.7" replace with "magento/product-community-edition": "2.2.2"
composer update
rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

During upgrade some error may our which need to be fixed.Then run following below commands after successful upgrade. It will time taking step.

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
chmod -R 777 generated
chmod -R 777 var/cache
chmod -R 777 pub
```

[Source Blog](https://ahmadvaqaskhan.blogspot.in/2018/01/upgrade-magento-21-to-22.html)

Comment: Are custom modules working fine after up-gradation?

Comment: It may or it may not. If there some issue then ,contact respective extension provider. If any issue, not much changes will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible (why it shouldn't be possible in the first place?)
Take care of extensions, because it is a Major version change and some of them may need to be updated/ removed.

Also please use documentation. All info is located here.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

Answer (score 0):

```
                            STEPS TO UPGRADE MAGENTO 2.1.x TO 2.2.3

1. bin/magento maintenance:enable   -- Enable Maintance mode

2. Update composer.json on root
      remove all "require" and add the following
        "require": {
                    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.2.3",
                    "composer/composer": "@alpha"
                    }

3. run "composer update"

4. clear root/var/cache,
                /page_cache,
                /generation,
        root/generation

5. sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/your_project_name/ give full permission

6. run "bin/magento setup:upgrade"

7. run "bin/magento maintenance:disable"


In between these we may face 2 errors :
    a. create a user with name "teachtech" or the name of user it is asking in error with full    permission
    b. connection code error code be found :
        add connection instance as - 

            public function __construct(
                            ...
                            \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface  $connection = null,
                            ...
                        ) {
                            ...
                        }

            where it is showing error



For further upgrades, change the version number:
```

composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.x --no-update

Feel free to ask question

Comment: Are custom modules working fine after up-gradation?