# Update Magento 2.1.8 to Magento 2.2 is giving

Tags: magento-2.1, upgrade, magento2.2.0

I tried to following steps to upgrade from 2.1.8 to 2.2.1 as mentioned in linked [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193010/how-to-update-magento-2-1-7-to-magento-2-2-is-it-possible-to-upgrade/201909?noredirect=1#comment279798_201909):

```
bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.0 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf var/generation/*
chmod +x bin/magento
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

but received the following error:

```
The requested package magento/product-community-edition 2.2.1 exists as magento/product-community-edition[2.1.8] but these are rejected by your constraint.
```

I can't see 2.1.8 anywhere in my composer.json file, but still received this error. Please let me know where should I fix?

Updating my `Composer.json` file:

```
    {
        "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
        "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
        "type": "project",
        "version": "2.2.1",
        "license": [
            "OSL-3.0",
            "AFL-3.0"
        ],
        "require": {
            "magento/product-community-edition": "2.2.1",
            "composer/composer": "@alpha"
 },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.4.0",
        "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "use-include-path": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": "app/code/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
```

.......

Comment: Another way to upgrade https://magecomp.com/blog/upgrade-magento-2-x-to-latest-version/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1: Access Your Server via SSH**

You need to connect your server via SSH.

**Step 2: Navigate to the Magento 2 Root Directory**

Once your SSH connection is up, you will need to move to your target application folder. In that application folder, you will find the public_html folder which is the root directory of Magento 2.

**Step 3: Upgrade Commands**

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2 --no-update
```

Then execute this all commands

```
 composer update
 rm -rf var/di var/generation
 php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 php bin/magento setup:di:compile
 php bin/magento cache:clean
 php bin/magento cache:flush
 php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: Hi Rohan, My root folder is /var/www/html/magento and hosted in AWS.  In step 3, after typing `composer update` I'm getting the error mentioned in my question. I could not see 2.1.8 in `composer.json`. Not sure how composer is picking 2.1.8.

Comment: After replacing my comoser.json and composer.lock files with magento 2.2.1 repository composer files, I successfully migrated Magento 2.2.1. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Happy to helping :) Happy Coding !!!