# Upgrade Issue : 2.0.0 to 2.1.7

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-2.0, magento-2.1.7, versioning

I am try to upgrade magento 2.0.0 to 2.1.7

Tutorial : [magento.stackexchange.com](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/197700/39050)

After upgrade Back-end changed to 2.1.7, but front end looking like,

[image]

Note :

> Refused to apply style from
>   MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled
>   Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "css: function(){return { empty:cart().summary_count == 0} }"
>   Message: cart is not a function
>       at css (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2624),

Note :

```
[DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #email: (More info: https://goo.gl/9p2vKq) <input name=​"login[username]​" value autocomplete=​"off" id=​"email" type=​"email" class=​"input-text" title=​"Email" data-validate=​"{required:​true, 'validate-email':​true}​" aria-required=​"true">​ <input name=​"login[username]​" value autocomplete=​"off" id=​"email" type=​"email" class=​"input-text" title=​"Email" data-validate=​"{required:​true, 'validate-email':​true}​" aria-required=​"true">​
(index):1 [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #newsletter: (More info: https://goo.gl/9p2vKq) <input name=​"email" type=​"email" id=​"newsletter" placeholder=​"Enter your email address" data-validate=​"{required:​true, 'validate-email':​true}​">​ <input name=​"email" type=​"email" id=​"newsletter" placeholder=​"Enter your email address" data-validate=​"{required:​true, 'validate-email':​true}​">​
(index):1 [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #pass: (More info: https://goo.gl/9p2vKq) <input name=​"login[password]​" type=​"password" autocomplete=​"off" class=​"input-text" id=​"pass" title=​"Password" data-validate=​"{required:​true, 'validate-password':​true}​" aria-required=​"true">​ <input name=​"login[password]​" type=​"password" autocomplete=​"off" class=​"input-text" id=​"pass" title=​"Password" data-validate=​"{required:​true, 'validate-password':​true}​" aria-required=​"true">​
(index):1 [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #popup-login-form: (More info: https://goo.gl/9p2vKq) <form class=​"form form-login" action=​"http:​/​/​localhost/​beta/​customer/​account/​loginPost/​" method=​"post" id=​"popup-login-form" novalidate=​"novalidate">​…​</form>​ <form class=​"form form-login" action=​"http:​/​/​localhost/​beta/​customer/​account/​loginPost/​" method=​"post" id=​"popup-login-form" novalidate=​"novalidate">​…​</form>​
(index):1 [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #send2: (More info: https://goo.gl/9p2vKq) <button type=​"submit" class=​"action login primary" name=​"send" id=​"send2">​…​</button>​ <button type=​"submit" class=​"action login primary" name=​"send" id=​"send2">​…​</button>​
jquery-migrate.js:41 JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.andSelf() replaced by jQuery.fn.addBack()
migrateWarn @ jquery-migrate.js:41
jquery-migrate.js:43 console.trace
migrateWarn @ jquery-migrate.js:43
/beta/customer/section/load/?sections=cart&update_section_id=false&_=1526040812897:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
customer-data.js:86 Uncaught Error: [object Object]
    at Object.<anonymous> (customer-data.js:86)
    at fire (jquery.js:3099)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.js:3211)
    at done (jquery.js:9312)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery.js:9720)
2knockout.js:3012 Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "css: function(){return { empty:cart().summary_count == 0} }"
Message: cart is not a function
    at css (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2624), <anonymous>:3:71)
    at update (knockout.js:3803)
    at ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.js:3004)
    at evaluateImmediate (knockout.js:1737)
    at Object.ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.js:1946)
    at knockout.js:3002
    at Object.arrayForEach (knockout.js:151)
    at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.js:2974)
    at applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal (knockout.js:2854)
    at applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal (knockout.js:2836)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run below command and check

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: Yes, after i did below is my screen shot.

Comment: Make sure all these command did you run?

Comment: yes, all my commands Successfully run.

Comment: Any idea about this error : https://snag.gy/BCHxpl.jpg

Comment: Almost done everything, what is the error mean :  Found 2 elements with non-unique id. screenshot -> https://snag.gy/s73RBx.jpg

Answer (score 0):

open the terminal and navigate to magento web root

**Set folder permissions**

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
chmod 777 ./app/etc
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
```

**Remove folder**

```
sudo rm -rf pub/static
sudo rm -rf var/cache
sudo rm -rf var/composer_home
sudo rm -rf var/generation
sudo rm -rf var/page_cache
sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed
```

**Run magento commands**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
chmod -R 777 var
chmod -R 777 pub
```

Comment: Thanks for your stuff, could you pls guide me how can i run these commands into windows

Comment: Please provide your magento root directory full path, So i can explain you.

Comment: chmod -R 777 pub    -> what is mean this line?

Comment: No, It's folder permission. 777 means Everyone can read write and execute. In a web server.

Comment: Here is link to help you, how to run command in windows. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186169/running-magento2-commands-in-windows-xampp?rq=1

Comment: Any idea about this error : https://snag.gy/BCHxpl.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77294/discussion-between-zus-and-vithal-bariya).

Comment: Almost done everything, what is the error mean :  Found 2 elements with non-unique id. screenshot -> https://snag.gy/s73RBx.jpg

Comment: In web-page you don't use same id multiple time. Your page found email, newsletter, pass etc. id in multiple time, So change same id.

Comment: Also if you have help any one ans. to resolve your problem so accept answer. it's help to other.

Comment: Sure, but still not working, once okay i will accept.. :)

Answer (score 0):

run below query in your magento 2 database
it will insert a row in core_config_data table:

INSERT INTO core_config_data (scope, scope_id, path, value) VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', '0');

If already added then change it to 0 then.

Comment: The table already present.

Comment: You just need to update those values in the table.

Comment: My table : https://snag.gy/ER0GvK.jpg

Comment: run this : INSERT INTO core_config_data (scope, scope_id, path, value) VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', '0');

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: Have you run content deploy command? and give permission to folder.

Comment: Yes , i did everything.

Comment: Rename .htaccess file from magento root and pub folder. (you can delete them as well, It's issue related to permission which is in .htaccess file)

Comment: If i remove .htaccess file form root folder backend not wokring

Comment: ok, Delete the lines from 40 to 112 in .htaccess of root magento

Comment: This is my  .htaccess ->  https://justpaste.it/5b2cm

Comment: Catch me on skype will explain you safal_jha

Comment: solved so-many things, how can i solve knockout.js error, Screen Shot : https://snag.gy/Jugo2G.jpg Error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "css: function(){return { empty:cart().summary_count == 0} }"

Comment: ahh, that's great  :)

Comment: Everything working except minicart  https://snag.gy/Jugo2G.jpg  the error is knockout.js.

Comment: Comment the // throw ex;

Comment: Its working, may i know the meaning of the error...