# How to Make Class or module to support M 2.1.7 and M 2.2.4 version in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, preference

I have one custom module which is working fine for M 2.1.7 
in that module, I extend `\Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type`

in M 2.2.4 they added a new class for core file and passed to `__construct`

that is `Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Selection\Collection\FilterApplier`
is a new file or class in M.2.2.4 and used in `\Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type::__construct`

but in M 2.1.7 above class is not used and also not exists

what is the best approach so that my extended class should support both the version that is (M 2.1.7 and aM 2.2.4)?

**Note:-** I cannot  use Plugin because I need to modify the logic in `_prepareProduct()` which is protected

Comment: Make 2 versions of your module?

Answer (score 0):

Change the construct method of your extended class to match the new construct method. The construct signature can change but it’s better if you keep the beginning of the signature the same and inject your extra classes before the $data array.

Make sure that when you call the `parent::__construct(...` you use the same order as in the construct of the parent object else you will get errors.

If you need an example let me know, I’ll add it.

Also, I suggest you use a context to inject multiple classes that way you can add/remove injections without having to change all subclasses.

Comment: How can i solve, Refused to apply style from MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "css: function(){return { empty:cart().summary_count == 0} }" Message: cart is not a function at css (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2624), while upgrading magento ver 2.0.0 to 2.1.7 @ https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/225412/57334

Comment: not sure I understand your comment, this looks like another issue. You should open a new question with this.

Comment: please add the your solution , but your solution should work fine with out any error in both version, that is i have 1 module which i installed in both version and should works fine

Comment: Paste your class, with the ‘__construct’  method, not the other methods and I’ll try to add the solution today.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not adding new/custom classes via DI(Dependency Injection) then probably you don't need the `__construct()` method in your child class otherwise you can use Object Manager directly for all the classes that you want to use and therefore you don't need to modify `__construct()`. This should work as far as I know. If anyone has a better solution, do let me know.

Comment: can you post the answer,  that is i have 1 module which i installed in both version and should works fine with out any error, and also i am not adding any new class, in m 2.2.4 core module  added new class but that class was not in M2.1.7 so it through error how to handle this

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest best solution is to version your module and use composer to pull in the appropriate version for the current version of Magento.

Alternatively if you can get away with not overriding the constructor then it shouldn't be an issue anymore. Obviously you may need to inject dependencies and the class constructor is the place to do that, so this might not really be acheivable. The other way to get your dependency would be to use the object manager directly outside of the constructor, this is generally not recommend but could be an option if your desperate.

Comment: tomorrow if we upgrade or any modification was doe we have to release in both right ?